# Using Socket.io client to connect to a different socket server

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I have a simple server written in C. Its capable of receiving (and sending) messages via a specified socket. I'd like to use [socket.io](http://socket.io/) client to send messages to this server. I setup a simple html page and tried connecting via

```
var socket = io('http://my.server.ip:8080');
```

My server gets the connection but then socket.io gives this error repeatedly on the javascript console.

```
GET http://my.server.ip:8080/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1431027762284-4 net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
```

I'm guessing my server should do a websocket 'handshake' to establish the connection. Is there a way to transmit a message in to a socket via JS with no handshake?

Please note my server does not use any standard, Its a rudimentary socket server that can receive and respond.

Comment: Quick answer : no.
Long answer : not the way you're doing it.
My guess is that if you want to work with socket.io/websockets, you should use it on both ends, or at least, have a server that implements a websocket server.

Answer (score 0):

There are web socket server libraries you can use.
a plain socket does not work with web sockets.